# How to get Heart Rate Data near by Real Time from Health Kit in iOS?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watch, healthkit

I have created a session in Watch and updating Heart Rate Data in Health Kit. Now, I want to Display the current Heart Rate in my iPhone Screen. Watch sensor update the Heart Rate Data in Health kit BUT iPhone Application in NOT able to Fetch Real-Time Data from the Health kit. I have tested out below TWO scenarios. I have also recalled this method/function using timer BUT it is not getting real-time data.

**Note: When I open Health App and Re-open my application then It will automatically refresh the data. If my application continuously in foreground then below code not refreshing latest data from the health kit**

**1. Tried to get Real Time Heart Rate Data using HKSampleQuery**

```
        let calendar = NSCalendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
        let startDate : NSDate = calendar.date(from: components)! as NSDate
        let endDate : Date = calendar.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.day, value: 1, to: startDate as Date)!

        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate as Date, end: endDate, options:[])

        //descriptor
        let sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)]

        self.heartRateQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: self.heartRateType, predicate: predicate, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, resultsHandler: { (query:HKSampleQuery,  results:[HKSample]?, error:Error?) in

            guard error == nil else { print("error in getting data"); return }

            self.collectCurrentHeartRateSample(currentSampleTyple: results)

        })

        self.healthStore.execute(self.heartRateQuery!)
```

---

**2. Tried to get Real Time Heart Rate Data using HKAnchoredObjectQuery**

```
    let sampleType : HKSampleType =  HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!
    let predicate : NSPredicate =  HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate as Date, end: endDate, options: [])
    let anchor: HKQueryAnchor = HKQueryAnchor(fromValue: 0)

    let anchoredQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: sampleType, predicate: predicate, anchor: anchor, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit) { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error ) in

        self.collectCurrentHeartRateSample(currentSampleTyple: samples!, deleted: deletedObjects!)

    }

    anchoredQuery.updateHandler = { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
        self.collectCurrentHeartRateSample(currentSampleTyple: samples!, deleted: deletedObjects!)
    }

    self.healthStore.execute(anchoredQuery)
```

=============================================

**Parsed the Data**

```
func collectCurrentHeartRateSample(currentSampleTyple : [HKSample]?, deleted : 

    [HKDeletedObject]?){

    //    func collectCurrentHeartRateSample(currentSampleTyple : [HKSample]?){

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.currentHeartRateSample = currentSampleTyple

                //Get Last Sample of Heart Rate
                self.currentHeartLastSample = self.currentHeartRateSample?.last
                print("lastSample : \(String(describing: self.currentHeartLastSample))")

                if self.currentHeartLastSample != nil {

                    let result = self.currentHeartLastSample as! HKQuantitySample

                    let heartRateBPM = result.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "count/min"))
                    let heartRateBPMUnit = "count/min"

                    let deviceUUID = self.currentHeartLastSample?.uuid
                    let deviceIdentity = result.sourceRevision.source.name
                    let deviceProductName = self.currentHeartLastSample?.device?.name
                    let deviceProductType = result.sourceRevision.productType
                    let deviceOSVersion = result.sourceRevision.version

                    let startDate = self.currentHeartLastSample?.startDate
                    let endDate = self.currentHeartLastSample?.endDate

                    self.aCollectionView.reloadData()
                }


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my own analysis regarding get nearby real-time Heart Rate.

**1.** If you are accessing Health Kit data using iPhone app, In this scenario, Health Kit DB NOT frequently updated/refreshed. So, your app not able to get real-time latest updated data through iPhone app.

**2.** Using a watch app, you can access near real-time data through Health Kit DB. Watch app is able to get the real-time latest updated Health Kit Data.

**3.** You need to transfer data from watch to iPhone app. Here is a code for your reference. You can write code as per your requirement. You just need to access Heart Rate through **HKQuery**

```
let defaultSession = WCSession.default

let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

var currentHeartRateSample : [HKSample]?

var currentHeartLastSample : HKSample?

var currentHeartRateBPM = Double()


//Get Heart Rate from Health Kit

func getCurrentHeartRateData(){

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
    let startDate : Date = calendar.date(from: components)!
    let endDate : Date = calendar.date(byAdding: Calendar.Component.day, value: 1, to: startDate as Date)!

    let sampleType : HKSampleType =  HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!
    let predicate : NSPredicate =  HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: [])
    let anchor: HKQueryAnchor = HKQueryAnchor(fromValue: 0)

    let anchoredQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: sampleType, predicate: predicate, anchor: anchor, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit) { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error ) in

        if samples != nil {

            self.collectCurrentHeartRateSample(currentSampleTyple: samples!, deleted: deletedObjects!)

        }

    }

    anchoredQuery.updateHandler = { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
        self.collectCurrentHeartRateSample(currentSampleTyple: samples!, deleted: deletedObjects!)
    }

    self.healthStore.execute(anchoredQuery)

}


//Retrived necessary parameter from HK Sample
func collectCurrentHeartRateSample(currentSampleTyple : [HKSample]?, deleted : [HKDeletedObject]?){

        self.currentHeartRateSample = currentSampleTyple

        //Get Last Sample of Heart Rate
        self.currentHeartLastSample = self.currentHeartRateSample?.last

        if self.currentHeartLastSample != nil {

            let lastHeartRateSample = self.currentHeartLastSample as! HKQuantitySample

            self.currentHeartRateBPM = lastHeartRateSample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "count/min"))
            let heartRateStartDate = lastHeartRateSample.startDate
            let heartRateEndDate = lastHeartRateSample.endDate

            //Send Heart Rate Data Using Send Messge

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                let message = [
                    "HeartRateBPM" : "\(self.currentHeartRateBPM)",
                    "HeartRateStartDate" : "\(heartRateStartDate)",
                    "HeartRateEndDate" : "\(heartRateEndDate)"
                ]

//Transfer data from watch to iPhone
                self.defaultSession.sendMessage(message, replyHandler:nil, errorHandler: { (error) in
                    print("Error in send message : \(error)")
                })

            }

        }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best method is to simply send the heart rate data to the phone app using Watch Communication.

In Watch code:

```
func send(heartRate: Int) {
    guard WCSession.default.isReachable else {
        print("Phone is not reachable")
        return
    }

    WCSession.default.sendMessage(["Heart Rate" : heartRate], replyHandler: nil) { error in
        print("Error sending message to phone: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
 }
```

and on phone you receive the data with:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String: Any]) {
    if let heartRate = message["Heart Rate"] {
        print("Received heart rate: \(heartRate)")
    } else {
        print("Did not receive heart rate =[")
    }
}
```

This should happen in pretty much real time. Alternatively there is another less reliable solution (imo) which is to just perform the heart rate query once every 5 seconds or so, but if I understand correctly you've already tried that and it didn't work.